# PHP: Generate QR Code with some descriptive text beside or below it

Tags: php, image, qr-code

Well, I was able to generate a QR code (dynamically) using http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ API.Now, I am stuck with another requirement where I need to add some text beside or below the image, describing the use of this QR code like say "SCAN ME for more offers!!". I wish to add company logo on that text too.

Is there an way to do, beside image manipulation api in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the QR codes on a web page, just add another div with the logo and or text.  If your goal is to produce a single image you can download and you want to produce it from your script you can use http://image.intervention.io/

It is still an API based implementation.  If you can clarify what you want to avoid and why and your end case I might be able to offer some other suggestions.

Comment: My intention is to generate a single image with QR Code and Text beside/beneath it. I'll try http://image.intervention.io/ and let you know how it goes.